# Homology of the Torus over a Module

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, free-modules

The homology groups $H_n(T,\mathbb{Z})$ for the torus $T$ are

$\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ for $n=1$,

$\mathbb{Z}$ for $n=0,2$.

Zero otherwise.

**Question:** Changing the coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ for coefficients in a $R$ free module, how do the homology groups look like? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_homology#Coefficients_in_R) says *"All of the constructions go through with little or no change"*. However, I can not follow why is this statement so clear. Could someone explain why is this? And how the homology groups could be computed?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your definition of $H_n(T,R) $ ? With $ H_n(T,\mathbb{Z}) \otimes_\mathbb{Z} R$ the result is clear

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_coefficient_theorem

Comment: This is because it turns out the definition of the boundary map in the cellular chain complex $C_*(T;R)$ does not depend on $R$. There is one generator in degree $0$, two in degree $1$, and one in degree $2$, and all of the boundary maps vanish based on the cell decomposition. I answered a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3123309/computing-homology-maps-with-non-integer-coefficients).